# DataFrame contains a text column with age with words "weeks" etc., how to convert it to int?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUHzT.jpg)I have a dataframe with the Age:

AgeInYears

0
1 year

1
1 year

2
2 years

3
3 weeks

4
2 years

5
1 month

6
3 weeks

7
3 weeks

I have to convert it to the age in int:

AgeInYears

0
1

1
1

2
2

3
0.06

4
2

5
0.08

6
0.06
7
0.06

first I started to replace everythin contains "years" `animals['AgeInYears'].str.replace('years','').str.replace('year','')`

but I have no clue how to make calculation for weeks and months. Lambda function?

Comment: Can't understand what your dataframe looks like. Paste the actual data please.

Comment: What is the dtype of `AgeInYears`?

Comment: I am sorry if smth is wrong, just have started to use this site. Here is how the original df looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUHzT.jpg

Comment: dtype is "object"

Comment: You could use a regex to take the numbers out and then hold them in an adjacent column, what's your end result

Answer (score 2):

you could create conditions that if weeks then take the value and divide by 52:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'AgeInYears':['1 year', '1 year', '2 years', '3 weeks', '2 years',
                                '1 month', '3 weeks', '3 weeks']})

# split the column into 2
df = df['AgeInYears'].str.split(expand=True)
df[0] = df[0].astype(int)

    0   1
0   1   year
1   1   year
2   2   years
3   3   weeks
4   2   years
5   1   month
6   3   weeks
7   3   weeks
```

then you can use `np.select` for your conditions:

```
conditions = [
    (df[1].str.contains('year')),
    (df[1].str.contains('week')),
    (df[1].str.contains('month'))
]

choices = [
    df[0],
    df[0]/52,
    df[0]/12
]

df['newValue'] = np.select(conditions,choices,default=np.nan)

    0   1       newValue
0   1   year    1.000000
1   1   year    1.000000
2   2   years   2.000000
3   3   weeks   0.057692
4   2   years   2.000000
5   1   month   0.083333
6   3   weeks   0.057692
7   3   weeks   0.057692
```